# Why does CHKDSK report no problems after a disk read error?

Tags: windows, windows-8, chkdsk

Recently, when copying files from one drive to another I noticed one file had a read error. In checking the event logs I saw a *lot* of "The IO operation at logical block address 9837 for Disk  was retried.".

So I decided to run chkdsk, which comes back clean. So I run checkdsk with /r and it came back with both:

```
A disk read error occurredc0000185
The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters
detected in file 59036 of name \MyFiles\Myfile.ext
```

Which was the file I originally had trouble with, plus another file. But chkdsk ultimate concludes with:

```
Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.
```

No, correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't a (previously un-corrupted, and fortunately backed-up) corrupted file (or two) with bad cluster be considered a problem?

Comment: It is but the file likely was moved to another sector.

Comment: In addition it says it does not have enough free space to replace bad sectors.  How much free space do you have on the hard drive?

Comment: If you don't use the `/r` parameter, `chkdsk` won't scan the disk for bad clusters, ignoring free space as well.

Comment: There's about 10% free which is why I was copying files to a new drive in the first place. Without '/r' chkdsk wasn't reporting any problems, which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug that affects Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Server 2012 and Server 2012 R2. CHKDSK under those OS is unable to populate the hidden $BadClus file, which contains a list of the defective sectors found in the disk.

If you run CHKDSK under Windows 7 it will work correctly, and it will mark those clusters as bad in the $BadClus file.

Let's hope Microsoft fixes this bug for Windows 10!

Answer (score 3):

Probably just in case you are running it before Windows starts - if it failed, Windows wouldn't boot.

Also, technically, the file *system* is ok, it's just that one file that has an issue.  Windows probably marked that sector as bad, and that file likely now has missing data.

You should really replace this drive.

Comment: The drive is being replaced for sure, but I would think there would be a warning status or something. Having the tool say there are no problems while the drive is going corrupt completely devalues the tool.

Comment: You're expecting too much out of CHKDSK, it's job is to make sure there's a consistent and valid filesystem, not repair corrupted files.  Error message could be better, but then it wouldn't be a Microsoft tool. ;)